# How to get comma separated value in one raw using sql server?

Tags: sql-server

I want to comma separated value in one row after some word comma separated value is a start in the table. Like this in 1 row UserA like category Cricket, Football. And in the 2 row UserB like category Reding, and, Wallyball. So now I want to this just category in one row like this Cricket, Football, Reading, Wallyball.

This is my query =>

```
select UserId,categorytext from Users
```

This is my current o/p =>

```
UserId  | categorytext
 1         UserA like category Cricket,Football  
 2         UserB like category Reding,and,Wallyball
```

I have tried this query =>

```
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @listStr = ''
SELECT @listStr = @listStr + categorytext + ','
FROM Users
SELECT SUBSTRING(@listStr , 1, LEN(@listStr)-1)
```

But using this query I am getting all the data in comma separated. I want to just after category word.

Comment: See [Example Uses of the STUFF String Function](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/tip-of-the-day.aspx?tkey=3934817c-1a03-4ac9-a0ba-55b2bfbaea0f&tkw=uses-of-the-stuff-string-function)

Comment: Can  you give an example of the output you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select UserId,STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', '+categorytext from Users i 
WHERE  i.UserId=o.UserId FOR XML PATH ('')),1,2,'') AS categorytext
from Users o
```